# R programming (beginner struggles): How can I make this list more efficiënt

Tags: r, datatable

I just started programming for the first time. I work on a research project with the tuber library. I already set up my api, this works fine.

Now I wanted to get my data into a table.
Therefore I want to combine 'get_stats' and 'get_video_details'.

To use the function 'get_stats' I need a 'video id'. Because I will work with 500 -1000 video Id's, I'm trying to find a way to overcome this:

```
my_list <- list(
                vid_list$items[[1]]$id,
                vid_list$items[[2]]$id,
                vid_list$items[[3]]$id,
                vid_list$items[[4]]$id,
                vid_list$items[[5]]$id
                ......
                )
View(my_list)
```

I figured out I will probably need a to use a loop. But I haven't found a way to work it out. Can anyone of you help me? It would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Try `lapply(vid_list$items, "[[", "id")`

Comment: @akrun, it works! Thank you so much! :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We extract the 'items', loop through the `list` with `lapply` and extract the "id"

```
lapply(vid_list$items, "[[", "id")
```